# Google Chrome Textbox focus bug

Tags: google-chrome, textbox

I had this happen a couple of times now, and I am not 100% sure of why. I have a normal textbox (code  below)

```
<input id="ddBox" type="text" /><span id="ddButton"></span><div id="dropDown"></div>
```

which is inside a floating div (jquery dialog to be precise).

in every single browser (including IE), but chrome I can select where the text pipe (|) is, just as in any other text program, however on chrome it will not let me do this, i'll give you an example:

```
this is some test text|
```

Now say I want to move the pipe to just after test:

```
this is some test| text
```

I just click there (basic stuff I know), but in chrome it just ignores the click completely, the only jquery .live(), .click(), and .bind() functions are nothing to do with the text box whatsoever.

I can type text into the box and if i press delete i can remove text from the box, just not select where the pipe is.

Running Chrome 9.0.576.0 dev
Ubuntu 10.10

bug is also apparent on:
Chrome (stable - latest release)
Windows XP Pro SP3

Comment: Did you report the bug to chromium dev?

Comment: in the process of doing that now, just thought i'd see if any other users of SO had come across this problem

Comment: I have a similar problem with you @Matt

Comment: I found this issue still exists on Chrome 79.0.3945.117 @ Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS